# Set font color based on sum of rgb indices for cell fill color

Tags: fonts, colors, cell, fill

I use a macro to set random fill colors, as shown:
Sub Color()

```
Dim rand1 As Integer
Dim rand2 As Integer
Dim rand3 As Integer

Randomize

rand1 = Int(255 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 1
Randomize
rand2 = Int(255 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 1
Randomize
rand3 = Int(255 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 1

Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(rand1, rand2, rand3)
Randomize
```

End Sub

I would like to set the font of the cell with the random color to be white or black by arbitrarily taking the sum of the 3 indices of the fill color, rand1+rand2+rand3. If that sum is >240, I want to set the font color to white; otherwise set it to black. As a very rookie VBA coder I have tried using "If-Else", but without success. Can someone please show me how to do this?
Thank you.
Bob K.

Answer (score 0):

No answers showed up, so I diddled with the macro recorder and came up with a pretty good solution. I won't show the solution unless someone besides me is interested.